# Какое условие позволит найти разных получателей?

Tags: sql

Имеется запрос 
SELECT * 
From contacts
В таблице contacts имеется столбец «получатель». Скажите, пожалуйста, какое значение позволит выгрузить только уникальных получателей?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Получатель`

Comment: `where not exists (select 1 from contacts where ...)`

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabel 
FROM dbname
WHERE tablename LIKE '%получатель%'
ORDER BY `dbname`.`tablename` ASC
```